# How to query many-to-many releationship in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .NET Core and EF Core for a web project. I'm struggling how to query a many-to-many releationship. This is what my models look like:

```
public class Begrip
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    [Url]
    public string URL { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<BegripCategory> Categories { get; set; } 
}

public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<BegripCategory> Begrippen { get; set; }
}

public class BegripCategory
{
    public int begripId { get; set; }
    public Begrip begrip { get; set; } 
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; } 
}
```

And my Database context:

```
public class PBBContext : DbContext
{
    public PBBContext (DbContextOptions<PBBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<PBB.Models.Movie> Movie { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PBB.Models.Begrip> Begrip { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<PBB.Models.Category> Category { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<PBB.Models.BegripCategory> BegripCategory { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        modelbuilder.Entity<BegripCategory>().HasKey(bc => new { bc.begripId, bc.categoryId });

        modelbuilder.Entity<BegripCategory>().HasOne(b => b.begrip).WithMany(bg => bg.Categories).HasForeignKey(bc => bc.begripId);
        modelbuilder.Entity<BegripCategory>().HasOne(c => c.category).WithMany(ca => ca.Begrippen).HasForeignKey(cc => cc.categoryId);
    }
}
```

What im trying to do is to return all the "Begrippen" in a JSON result with all the corresponding "Categories", however, I can't figure out how to get the list of "Categories" for them.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

EF Core won't load related properties automatically, so you'll need to explicitly do this, but something like the following should do the trick:

```
var result = context.Begrip
    .Include(x => x.Categories)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.category);
```

Note, intellisense doesn't always work on `.ThenInclude` at the moment, but the code should still compile even if it gets a red underline.

If you're returning this to the view or an API, you'll likely want to map it to a DTO so you don't have to deal with `.Categories[0].category.Name` etc.

Comment: Its called [Eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: in EF Core 2.1 using VS 2017 15.9.7 that doesn't compile.

Comment: In fact, now that I look at your answer, `Begrip` doesn't have a `Categories` property, only a `BegripCategory` property. Downvoting, please update answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: Also, curious how one would go about iterating through a variable number of `BegripCategory` child entities in a `Select()` statement. Is that possible? If so, could you show how?

Comment: Still compiles fine for me under those conditions.  Begrip *does* have a Categories property, the BegripCategory property is on the context, not the Begrip class.

Answer (score 24):

If you need to filter a Many-to-Many relationship describe below I recomend to use a **LinQ Enumerable Any method** like this:

```
return result.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(c => c.category == categoryId));
```

To return a filtered list of entities related by a specific category.

[EntityFrameworkCore Relationship query example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Extending @Richard's answer :

I noticed in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.6 when I do following:

```
            return _context.Begrip
            .Include(x => x.Categories)
                .ThenInclude(y => y.<nothing typed in here yet>)
```

IntelliSense at first tells me that *y* if of type *ICollection* of *BegripCategory* presenting methods suitable for collections what is confusing especially that when I start typing "category" (in place of "nothing typed in here yet") IntelliSense changes as if we were dealing with only a single instance instead of *ICollection*

Just a tiny remark, but I hope it will help to save a few minutes time confusion.