# Problem querying a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

VS 2019
EF Core (SQL Server)

Prior to EF Core Many-to-Many queries were straightforward.  I am trying to convert my .NET project to .NET Core, but it does not automatically create the joins like previously.

Say for example you have a many-to-many relationship User <-> Role.  Let's call the join table UserRole.

So:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class Role
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class UserRole
{
    public string UserId;
    public string RoleId;
}
```

Given that I have an instance of a User object (see below), how do I write a query to give me the Name of all of the Roles associated with that User?

```
var user = _context.User
    .Where(u => u.Name == "Fred")
    .First();
```

I have seen this [How to query many-to-many releationship in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500007/how-to-query-many-to-many-releationship-in-ef-core) but there is no answer that works.  Surely someone must have done this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var user = _context.User
    .Where(u => u.Name == "Fred")
    .Include(u => u.UserRoles)
    .ThenInclude(u => u.Role)
    .First();
var roleNames = user.UserRoles.Select(x => x.Role.Name);
```

Reference: [Eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading)

Comment: crgolden.  Seems to work, marked as answer.  Thanks.