# Linq Query For Many to Many Relation within Intersecting Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 models and a Intersecting model.

I want to extract **Ticket** and co-responding **Users** for specific **Ticket Id** using *Linq Lambda Expression*

model 1: Ticket

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<UserTicket> UserTickets { get; set; }
    }
```

model 2: User

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        // Id: string, UserName: string Automatic generated by ASP.NET Core Identity

        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public ICollection<UserTicket> UserTickets { get; set; }
    }
```

Intersecting Model: UserTicket

```
public class UserTicket
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int TicketId { get; set; }
        public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) {}

        // public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } ****Using IdentityDbContext

        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserTicket> UserTickets { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           
            builder.Entity<UserTicket>().HasKey(ut => new { ut.UserId, ut.TicketId });
            builder.Entity<UserTicket>()
                .HasOne(t => t.Ticket)
                .WithMany(t => t.UserTickets)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.TicketId);
            builder.Entity<UserTicket>()
                .HasOne(t => t.User)
                .WithMany(t => t.UserTickets)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId);
         }
    }
```

I am very beginner in this Field, Tried a lot, but can't solve this.
please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
dbcontext.Tickets.where(t=>t.Id==TICKET_ID)
  .include(t=>t.UserTickets)
  .ThenInclude(ut=>ut.User);
```

Check similar question: [How to query many-to-many releationship in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500007/how-to-query-many-to-many-releationship-in-ef-core)
.

It's better to have a look at [entity-framework-core Tutorials](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx) to learn basics of Entity Framework Core;

Answer (score 0):

You can do following LINQ query to get the list of all the users for a specific ticketId:

```
await DataContext.UserTicket
    .Include(t => t.User)
    .Where(t => t.TicketId == ticketId)
    .Select(t => t.User)
    .ToListAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be something like this:

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
   //Your ticket properties
   public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Users {get; set;}
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    //Your user properties        
}

//query

var ticket = DataContext.Tickets
  .Include(t => t.UserTickets)
    .ThenInclude(ut => ut.User)
  .Where(t => t.Id == {ID})
  //Here initialize required properties
  .Select(t => new TicketViewModel {Users = t.UserTickets.Select(ut => new UserViewModel {Id = ut.User.Id /* etc */})})
  .FirstOrDefault()
```